# Restore or mount whole drive image backup from dd

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, backup, dd

I had some weird behavior every night on my ubuntu server, where one of my NVME disks would stop working, and I'd get IO errors until I reboot, in which case everything would work fine.

The drive in question wasn't a boot drive, it was mounted at `/var/lib`.

I decided to replace it, and before then I was going to create a disk image of the possibly failing drive, so I could replace it and just copy the data onto a new drive.

Following the instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DriveImaging

I created a handful of backup images.  When creating these images, I would remove the entry that mounts the drive from /etc/fstab and reboot, then use dd to create an image of the unmounted drive: `dd if=/dev/nvme1n1p1 | bzip2 > /media/ssd_backup_2023-09-11.bz2`

Now that the new drive is installed I tried to copy the image onto the new drive (once again according to the documentation here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DriveImaging: `bzcat /media/ssd_backup_2023-09-11.bz2 | dd of=/dev/nvme1n1`.

But that didn't work.

I tried mounting the image directly (after extracting it from the bz2 file), and copying the files over.  Didn't work.  Assuming I messed up something on the command line, I tried copying out the image files and mounting them on my desktop from the GUI, and I get the same errors I get when I tried mounting them from the command line:

`Error mounting /dev/loop4 at /media/tshannon/e0ce1 331-ddOf-47a6- b104-c142b282a823: wrong Fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/ loop4, missing codepage or helper program, or other error (udisks-error- quark, 0)`

DMESG shows the following:

`[248810.448466] loop4: detected capacity change from 0 to 1233800 [248810.652202] /dev/loop4: Can't open blockdev [248810.652330] EXT4-fs (loop4): bad geometry: block count 244189952 exceeds size of device (154225 blocks) [248812.330897] /dev/loop4: Can't open blockdev [248812.331033] EXT4-fs (loop4): bad geometry: block count 244189952 exceeds size of device (154225 blocks) [248998.384382] loop19: detected capacity change from 0 to 1233800`

So are my drive images hosed?

Comment: The uncompressed dd image is 631 MB of a 1TB ssd, so I'm guessing the drive actually crapped out as dd tried to image it.  I can't resize2fs the image and I can e2fsk it either.

Comment: Try `ddrescue` on the "crapped out" drive?

Comment: @Hannu The server is in a datacenter, and they swapped out the drive remotely.  They are shipping me the old SSD now.  We'll see.